# Why didn't the Apollo 13 crew wear their spacesuits in the LM?

Tags: apollo-13

In the Apollo 13 movie, the crew take refuge in the Lunar Module, the temperature drops and they suffer the cold in their shirtsleeves.

Is this accurate?  Is there a reason they couldn't wear their A7L pressure suits to keep warm?  I don't mean powered up with their helmets on, just the main body of the suit to provide some extra insulation

Comment: Donning and wearing a pressure suit with three persons in the very small LM cabin designed for only two astronauts would have been difficult.

Comment: @Uwe Couldn't they don them in the CM and move to the LM?  I know space was tight in the LM, but there were places for the two lander crew at their flight stations, and the diagram on Wikipedia shows a crewman sitting on the engine cover - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/LEM-linedrawing.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cold was unpleasant but tolerable. Trying to function in space suits for days would have been worse. As Uwe said in the comments, they are bulky. They are also uncomfortable and stiff (although the greatest stiffness comes from pressurization). And, probably not least, they are not designed to accept and retain human waste for days. Taking them off every time you needed to go would have been a huge hassle.

I've read *Lost Moon*/*Apollo 13* and also the earlier book *Thirteen: The Apollo Flight that Failed*, and it doesn't sound like the idea of using space suits as overcoats was even considered.

Comment: As I recall, at least one of the Apollo crews spent much of the transit time _au naturel_ due to the hassles of waste management.

Comment: @AlexHajnal citation needed

Comment: @OrganicMarble Will provide if I can track it down