# Does space sickness determine when astronauts have their last meal?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, space-shuttle, astronaut-lifestyle, food, space-sickness

During the shuttle program how long before launch would an astronaut eat?  With almost 50% of astronauts experiencing space adaptation syndrome, and the possibility of vomiting, did the astronauts prefer (or were encouraged) to go to orbit on an empty stomach?

I am not asking if they chose not to eat because of pre-flight stress (as discussed in the link in the comment). I'm wondering if there was any consideration for vomiting in deciding when to eat?

Comment: That link mentions "pre-flight stress prevents them from enjoying the meal...of the STS-41D crew, 'most of us ate nothing or very lightly. I had a piece of toast'".  Was there any consideration for vomiting in deciding when to eat?

Comment: Other than the title how is my question a duplicate? I'm asking something specifically different from the question What do astronauts eat for pre-flight breakfast?  I did not ask what they ate, or if pre-flight stress was an issue.  I'm asking about space adaptation syndrome and the timing of eating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The prelaunch timeline for the crew was closely scheduled. Shuttle crews were awakened ~ 5 hours prior to the scheduled liftoff time  and ate a meal shortly after they woke up and got dressed. Depending on the scheduled liftoff time, the crew may have been sleep shifting for a week or so prior to launch day.

[image]

Source - [SCOM](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf), page 5.1-1 Normal Procedures Summary

What and how much they ate at that time was subject to personal choice as discussed here: [What do astronauts eat for pre-flight breakfast?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/what-do-astronauts-eat-for-pre-flight-breakfast)

If they feared space sickness they could choose their food appropriately.

They left for the pad ~ 3 hours prior to the scheduled liftoff time.