# What are the prelaunch procedures that astronauts follow before the launch?

Tags: spacex, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle

What procedures do the astronauts follow, like the suit-up procedures and communication checks that happen before the launch. And how will the astronaut's family meet the astronauts prior to the launch and what are the procedures the family must follow in order to meet them? *(In short I would like to know what the astronauts do a day before and on the day of launch)*

***I am requiring this information for a novel and it would be appreciated if it is explained in detail***

Comment: The live NASA-TV coverage of Shuttle launches used to cover what the astronauts were doing in detail starting with their departure from the Operations and Checkout building, including views inside the orbiter as the astronauts entered and were assisted into their seats by technicians. However much of this activity occurred 2-3 hours prior to launch and most clips that I see online only show the last hour or so before launch where you don't see much, and all you hear are the com checks. But coverage of the early Crew Dragon missions was similar in detail and video should still be available.

Comment: During the Apollo era astronauts would meet their families a day or two before launch at a designated open air site. They had to stand at some distance from their families to minimize the possibly of contracting an illness. They could see & speak with each other, but not touch each other.

Comment: I think it's going to be important for you to specify *which astronauts* you want the answer for.  Apollo, Space Shuttle, Dragon, and Soyuz are all different, and the procedures have varied even within any given program. There's not one standardized astronaut procedure now-and-forever. Are you asking about modern "going to the ISS" missions? Where from? (A Soyuz launch from Baikonur is going to be different from a Dragon launch from Kennedy.)

Comment: There is some shuttle info in this answer, but the linked reference has the full timeline https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39955/6944